# Grails - Optimistic Locking - Time between two possible updates

Tags: hibernate, grails

I'm generally using optimistic locking throughout my project. I now have the case that I retrieve and the update of an object via AJAX (I don't know if that influences Grails' or Hibernate's behaviour at all).

For the update I use a simple service method containing `object.save()` only. If I update an object once I don't have a problem. If I update the same object right after the first update I get the `StaleObjectStateException` but if I wait some time I don't get the exception.

My question now is how long I have to wait to do the second update? Is there a general rule? Is there something that determines how long I have to wait (I noticed that it's not always the same)?

Comment: Try change object.save() to object.save(flush:true). flush: true will grant that your change is flushed to database before continue to next line. The general rule isn't use flush:true, but in some cases it's necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the problem was something else. I'm using a timestamp as `version` (I'm thinking about changing this). However, the MySQL version I used didn't support milliseconds - so, everytime I updated an object the milliseconds were rounded resulting in problems if the rounded value was greater than the original one. I updated the MySQL version and didn't have any problems anymore.